# Unable to print the variable right after set it in Azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops-pipelines

Please see the code below. It is unable to print the variable right after **set.variable** task! I had feelings and tried as well that NOTHING below the **set.variable** task will be executed at all. This is so annoying and How can I solve it?

```
  - bash: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BUILD_NUMBER]$(Build.BuildId)"
      echo $(BUILD_NUMBER) // BUILD_NUMBER: command not found
    displayName: Set 

  - bash: |
      echo "you shall saw build id below"
      echo $(BUILD_NUMBER) // Same line and this is OK!
    displayName: Print
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That makes sense to me, honestly. You run the `##vso[task.setvariable]` command, and it makes the variable available to subsequent tasks *once the current task is finished running*. It doesn't alter the environment of the *current* task. Since you clearly already have the data available in the current task, it shouldn't matter.

You don't even need to do what you're doing: You can reference variables as environment variables by replacing periods with underscores. I.E. `$BUILD_BUILDID`. Refer to the documentation.